# How do I declare multiple flags in PlaySound function statement in VB6?

Tags: vb6, flags

I am writing a VB6 program and need some help with the syntax of the PlaySound function declaration. I have written the attached snippet and it succeeds in playing `Tada.wav` but does not reflect all the flags.

Can I have more than one `dwFlag`, or am I limited to just one ?

I would like dwFlags to include `SND_ASYNC`, `SND_FILENAME` and `SND_LOOP`.

Here is the code I have tried so far:

```
 Dim RetVal As Variant

 Private Const SND_ASYNC As Long = &H80

 Private Const SND_FILENAME As Long = &H20000 

 Private Const SND_LOOP As Long = &H8

 Private Declare Function PlaySound Lib "winmm.dll" Alias _

         "PlaySoundA" (ByVal lpszName As String, ByVal hModule As Long, _

          ByVal dwFlags As Long) As Long

 Private Sub Command3_Click()

        RetVal = PlaySound("C:\Program Files\@VickEdu\Vocab!\Tada.wav",_

                            0&,_

                            SND_FILENAME Or SND_ASYNC Or SND_LOOP)


 End Sub

Private Sub Command4_Click()

    RetVal = PlaySound("C:\Program Files\@VickEdu\Vocab!\Tada.wav",_

                        0&, _

                        SND_FILENAME & SND_ASYNC & SND_LOOP)

  End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The way you've done it in your `Command3` handler is correct (using `Or`).

Your issue is that you've defined the wrong value for `SND_ASYNC`. Change:

```
Private Const SND_ASYNC As Long = &H80
```

to:

```
Private Const SND_ASYNC As Long = &H1
```

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks for your generosity in responding. After reading your remarks I encountered some additional information on my question at the following link http://www.vb6.us/tutorials/playsound-api.

It stated:  "The only "gotcha" with Playsound is the creation of dwFlag. It is possible to add too many flags, which will result in an overflow error."

It then went on to give a useful discussion of the meaning of the available flags.

Comment: Were you not able to get it to work using my answer? I did a test and was able to successfully combine the three flags you're using (file/loop/asnyc).